# How to Itreate through Json

Tags: python, json, api, indexing

I need [0] to increase everytime and fetch the data when index change. from 0 to 13

```
import requests as r
import json 

url = "https://services6.arcgis.com/bKYAIlQgwHslVRaK/arcgis/rest/services/CasesByRegion_ViewLayer/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json" 
response = urlopen(url)
Data= json.load(response )
```

```
for index in Data:
    list = Data['features'][0]['attributes']
    [0]+1
    print(list)
```

Comment: This is such a basic Python question, I feel like it would be better for you to learn some fundamentals first and _then_ fetch and process the data over the REST API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another simple approach without using urllib:

```
import requests as r
import json

url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
response = r.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

requests.get().json() delivers the complete dict from the response payload:

```
import requests as r
response = r.get(url)
Data = response.json()
```

Your json.load() doesn't work as expected because response is a dictionary from the requests module, containing some HTTP stuff like status code, reason, encoding. For API calls, this is not what you want (HTTP errors should be handled with exceptions). What you want is response.json() or response.text.

Also, you imported requests but didn't use it? I don't know about urlopen(). Use requests.get().